# How to prevent label/symbol duplication/cutting in Leaflet/Mapserver(WMS)

Tags: leaflet, gis, wms, mapserver

[image: label/symbol duplication with leaflet/mapserver with wms]

As you can see the labels are duplicated and sometimes cutoff. That is because one tile doesn't know about the other tile. How can I prevent?

Disabling Partial labels helps a bit with the cutoff but the duplication is still there:

[image: disabling label partials]

Thanks

Comment: If one of the labels are coming together with the map tiles, then you need to use another map tile server.

Comment: Practically I'm controlling both the server and the viewer. What you're saying is that I should generate the labels on the leaflet side and not on the mapserver side?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346467/preventing-clipped-labels-from-qgis-server-wms-in-leaflet-js

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @IvanSanchez's reply here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346467/preventing-clipped-labels-from-qgis-server-wms-in-leaflet-js.

You can actually set the tileSize to the width/height of your map and you won't have these kind of problems because the whole map would consist of 1 tile (although this solution will put extra strain on the MapServer). tileSize is part of the GridLayer definition: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer.

```
Param: tileSize
Default: 256
Type: number|Point
Def: Width and height of tiles in the grid. Use a number if width and height are equal, or L.point(width, height) otherwise.
```